# Redux Store not connected to React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have this plunkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/8rSWX6GAtf50jGx0CSNM?p=preview):

```
ReactDOM.render(
        <ReactRedux.Provider store={store}>
          <div>
            <MyComponent/>
            <button onClick={loadInitialValues} className="btn btn-default">
              LOAD VALUES
            </button>
          </div>
        </ReactRedux.Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Why my React Component (MyComponent) is not updated when the button "*LOAD VALUES*" is clicked? It seems that everything is fine. The action is dispatched, then in my reducer I look for the action "`LOAD_VALUES`" and I return the new values, but the React Component doesn't get updated and stays the same.

Thanks!

Comment: have you connected MyComponent to the store?

Comment: Can you show us the source of `MyComponent` ?

Comment: Could you check out the full "working" ;-) source code of the example under the plunkr link above? You should also be able to run and test it! Normally, it works to have the component connected to the store like in the plunkr but I am doing something wrong here I think. If you have any ideas or you aren't able to read the source code please write me a comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var suaReducer = function(state = Immutable.Map({
  modalProps: Immutable.Map({
    editMode: false,
    paymentType: Immutable.Map({})
  })
}), action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case LOAD_VALUES:
      return state.merge({
        modalProps: Immutable.Map({
          editMode: true,
          paymentType: Immutable.Map({
            name: "TEST",
            notes: "TEST",
            amounts: [{
              amount: 100,
              year: 2017
            }]
          })
        })
      });
  }

  return state;
}
```

Just changed you `switch` statement instead of `action` use `action.type` since `action` is an object you are dispatching (`{type: LOAD_VALUES}`).
Updated your plunker sample so it looks like it works now.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: Glad I was able to help!